# Para que é usado Bind(Include = "Propriedade")?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, atributos

Ao criarmos um CRUD com *scalfold* no ASP.NET MVC, nos métodos de `POST`, temos o seguinte código:

```
 public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Nome")] Grupo grupo) {...}
```

Para que é usado esse `[Bind]`? Quando usamos `Grupo grupo`, já não é feito o Bind automaticamente?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sua observação está correta. Mas este atributo anula todo o *binding* já definido e determina que só as propriedades listadas no atributo serão usadas. Assim a ação (neste caso) não poderá popular propriedades indevidamente. Então se vier algo pelo `POST` que não sejam `Id` e `Nome` não serão considerados.

Você já viu algum `[Bind(Exclude = "AlgumaPropriedade")]`? Este atributo mantêm todas as propriedades do *binding* exceto esta propriedade listada.

Isto vale só para o local onde o atributo foi usado.

Pode ser usado como uma facilitador ou como segurança para garantir que nada além do que é necessário será afetado inadvertidamente.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).