# O que estou fazendo com este método?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho o seguinte método:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Criar([Bind(Include = "CategoriaId,Nome")] Categoria categoria)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        categoria.CategoriaId = Guid.NewGuid();
        db.Categorias.Add(categoria);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(categoria);
}
```

Gostaria de uma explicação sobre ele, o que estou fazendo no construtor quando uso o `([Bind(Include = "CategoriaId,Nome")]` O que exatamente quer dizer o `BIND` ?

Comment: Recomendo visualizar esta pergunta que tem resposta bem completa resposta do [bigown](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45459/para-que-%C3%A9-usado-bindinclude-propriedade)

Comment: Veja se essa pergunta *linkada* acima responde o que deseja

Comment: Ok, devo remover essa que eu fiz ?

Comment: por agora não precisa, talvez nem vá precisar. Talvez sua pergunta seja diferente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagina que o seu objeto `Categoria` tem um campo `ind_exclusao`, alem dos campos `CategoriaId` e `Nome`.

Imagina que você tem uma `view` para editar uma categoria onde você pode trocar o nome dela.

Essa `view` tem um `imput` com o Nome da categoria...

Quando essa view faz um `POST` ele manda para o servidor os dados da categoria no `body` do `request`.

O servidor por sua vez converte esses dados em um objeto `Categoria`, que é o que chega no seu `Controller`.

Esse é o funcionando padrão...

No caso do editar acima ele não pode excluir, ou seja, o objeto `ind_exclusao` sempre chega `falso`.

Se alguém simular um `POST` no seu servidor, não usando a sua view, e coloca no corpo do `request` um objeto Categoria com id XXX, nome YYYY e indicador de exclusão True o seu `Controller` (que não sabe se está recebendo um POST da view ou não) vai converter os dados do corpo no seu objeto Categoria que entra no controller.

Essa conversão dos dados do corpo do `POST` no Objeto que entra no Controller é chamado de `BIND`.

Quando você coloca o `[Bind(Include = "CategoriaId,Nome")]` no assinatura do método do `Controller` você obriga o servidor a pegar APENAS o `CategoriaId` e o `Nome` do corpo do POST e converter no objeto. Nesse caso, caso no corpo exista o indicador de exclusão ele ira ser ignorado.

Isso é uma medida de segurança e é aconselhável ser usado.

Se tiver dúvidas pergunta que detalho melhor a resposta.