# Qual é a finalidade da característica "[Bind("ID,Title,ReleaseDate,Genre,Price")]" em um método?

Tags: c#, .net, característica-linguagem, asp.net-core, atributos

Estou criando um projeto em [ASP.NET Core MVC](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app-xplat/start-mvc) para fins de aprendizagem. Em numa determinada parte do guia da Microsoft quando é abordada a técnica de *scaffold* para gerar o *controller* e as *views* correspondentes as ações do *controller*, me deparei com uma instrução em alguns métodos que me deixou com dúvida em bem confuso.

Veja abaixo o método `Create` como exemplo:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ID,Title,ReleaseDate,Genre,Price")] Movie movie)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _context.Add(movie);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    return View(movie);
}
```

Veja a instrução antes da declaração do parâmetro `movie`. É neste ponto que surgiu minha dúvida e me deixou confuso.

## Dúvidas

1. Que tipo de característica é a instrução
   `[Bind("ID,Title,ReleaseDate,Genre,Price")]` passada na assinatura
   do método Create?
2. Qual seria a finalidade desta característica quando usada em um
   método?

Comment: Sei que serve para definir quais atributos do objeto devem ser passados no HttpPost, da mesma forma, há outra instrução para excluir atributos do `Bind` feito durante o Post no objeto. Não tenho maiores informações para formular uma resposta decente, então deixo apenas como comentário mesmo =] https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.bindattribute(v=vs.118).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Que tipo de característica é a instrução [Bind("ID,Title,ReleaseDate,Genre,Price")] passada na assinatura do método Create?

São atributos. [Podem ser usados em outras partes do código](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44900/101).

> Qual seria a finalidade desta característica quando usada em um método?

É uma forma de definir metadados para a aplicação. Isto pode ser usado pelo compilador, pelo *framework* geral (.NET), o *framework* específico (ASP.NET por exemplo) ou até sua própria aplicação.

Esta informação pode ser obtida com [reflexão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/506768/101) e usada da forma como for mais conveniente.

Neste caso o ASP.NET Core pega a informação ali e mapeia no objeto, então as *strings* recebidas pelo HTTP com os nomes citados ali serão usados para compor o objeto `movie`. O *framework* sabe como fazer isto, você só precisa saber como usar o atributo para indicar o que ele deve fazer.

É até uma [medida de segurança contra injeção de dados indevidos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/255695/101).

É uma [forma mais declarativa de programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81854/101) que é útil em alguns casos para reduzir o [*boiler plate*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/10575/101) (código para fazer operações enfadonhas, repetitivas, só para resolver algo antes de fazer o que realmente precisa, ele cuida de uma burocracia necessária, mas que não agrega nada específico à solução).

[Outro exemplo de uso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45459/101).

Comment: Isto também serve para proteger o controller contra [overpost](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-basic-crud-functionality-with-the-entity-framework-in-asp-net-mvc-application#overpost).

Comment: Sem dúvida.....