# O que é um ataque Over-posting?

Tags: terminologia, segurança, post, asp.net-core

Me deparei com o termo [Over-posting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app-xplat/controller-methods-views) enquanto seguia o guia da Microsoft de criação de aplicações em ASP.NET Core.

Eu havia feito [uma pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/254806/27190) a respeito do uso de atributos na assinatura de um método, que neste caso, foi o atributo `Bind` seguido dos campos que foram submetidos pelo formulário. No qual este atributo tinha a finalidade de proteger o *controller* contra um *over-posting*.

Entretanto, a minha maior dúvida é a respeito do tal do *over-posting*, eu sei como me proteger dele neste cenário, mas não sei o que ele é de fato.

## Dúvidas

1. O que é um ataque de tipo Over-posting?
2. Quando e como ocorre um ataque deste tipo?
3. Quais danos ele pode causar para a minha aplicação?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isso guarda alguma semelhança com o [SQL Injection](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3864/101), só que agora por causa de uma automação que um *framework* fornece para diminuir o trabalho de codificação. Geralmente ocorre com MVC e ORM.

O que costuma ocorrer é que o que vem do URL é desserializado para um objeto que é persistido posteriormente no banco de dados. Se você não limitar o que deve ser desserializado é possível mandar dados que não deveriam ser alterados por algo que vem de fora. Pode mudar uma senha, trocar o saldo, zerar algum histórico, mudar uma identidade, etc.

Dependendo do sistema pode causar o mesmo estrago que o [SQL Injection](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/100730/101), embora seja provável que ocorra algo menos pior.

É o velho problema de ter que validar **todas** as informações que vem de fonte externa a aplicação. Ocorre quando faz na mão e quando não sabe usar o *framework* direito. Você nunca tem controle sobre o que de fora, só aceite o que você tem certeza que não tem perigo, bloqueie todo o resto.

O `Bind` ajuda, mas não resolve tudo. Tem casos que a validação não é "pode ou não pode" receber o campo, tem o jeito que pode e o jeito que não pode.

A maioria das aplicações que tem por aí está sujeita a isso, inclusive escritas por pessoas experientes. Já vi curso tido como bom que deixa esta brecha sem ser coberta, ensina-se fazer o estrago, mas não como combatê-lo.

Veja mais em [Usar validação via cliente é suficiente?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13298/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).